# Insert method for Room Database working fine, but Update will not

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, android-room

I'm trying to get a limited database of character stats (i.e. health, mana, etc.) to work. The Insert method works fine, but I can't seem to get the Update method to do the same.

I'm using essentially the same logic for Update that I am for Insert. I'm creating an ASyncTask method to update, then applying that to an instance of the Stats class that references the database's values.

*Update - Posted DAO.

Repository Class:

```
private StatsDatabase statsDatabase;
    private StatsDao mStatsDao;


    public StatsRepo(Context context) {
        statsDatabase = StatsDatabase.getDatabase(context);
        mStatsDao = statsDatabase.statsDao();
    }

    public void populateStats () {
        Stats stats = new Stats();
        stats.setHealth(15); stats.setMana(0); stats.setStr(1); stats.setCon(1);
        stats.setAgi(1); stats.setIntel(1); stats.setAlign(0);
        insertStats(stats);
    }

    public void testUpdate() {
        Stats stats = new Stats();
        stats.setHealth(100);
        updateStats(stats);
    }

public void insertStats(final Stats stats) {
        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
                mStatsDao.insert(stats);
                return null;
            }
        }.execute();
    }

    public void updateStats(final Stats stats) {
        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
                mStatsDao.update(stats);
                return null;
            }
        }.execute();
    }

}
```

Database Class:

```
@Database(entities = { Stats.class }, version = 1, exportSchema = false)

public abstract class StatsDatabase extends RoomDatabase {

    private static StatsDatabase INSTANCE;

    public abstract StatsDao statsDao();

    public static StatsDatabase getDatabase(Context context) {
        if (INSTANCE == null) {
            synchronized (StatsDatabase.class) {
                if (INSTANCE == null) {
                    INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(),
                            StatsDatabase.class, "stats_db")
                            .allowMainThreadQueries()
                            .build();
                }
            }
        }
        return INSTANCE;
    }
    public static void destroyInstance() {
        INSTANCE = null;
    }

}
```

Stats Class:

```
public class Stats {
    @PrimaryKey (autoGenerate = true)
    private int id;
    private int health;
    private int mana;
    private int str;
    private int con;
    private int agi;
    private int intel;
    private int align;

    public Stats(){
    }
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public int getHealth() {
        return health;
    }
    public int getMana() {
        return mana;
    }
    public int getStr() {
        return str;
    }
    public int getCon() {
        return con;
    }
    public int getAgi() {
        return agi;
    }
    public int getIntel() {
        return intel;
    }
    public int getAlign() {
        return align;
    }
    public void setHealth(int health) {
        this.health = health;
    }
    public void setMana(int mana) {
        this.mana = mana;
    }
    public void setStr(int str) {
        this.str = str;
    }
    public void setCon(int con) {
        this.con = con;
    }
    public void setAgi(int agi) {
        this.agi = agi;
    }
    public void setIntel(int intel) {
        this.intel = intel;
    }
    public void setAlign(int align) {
        this.align = align;
    }
}
```

Dao Class:

```
@Query("SELECT * from STATS")
    List<Stats> loadAllStats();

    @Query("SELECT health from Stats")
    int loadHealth();

    @Query("SELECT mana from Stats")
    int loadMana();

    @Query("SELECT str from Stats")
    int loadStrength();

    @Query("SELECT con from Stats")
    int loadConstitution();

    @Query("SELECT agi from Stats")
    int loadAgility();

    @Query("SELECT intel from Stats")
    int loadIntelligence();

    @Query("SELECT align from Stats")
    int loadAlignment();


    @Insert
    void insert(Stats stats);

    @Update
    void update(Stats stats);

    @Delete
    void delete(Stats stats);

    @Query("DELETE FROM Stats")
    void deleteAll();

}
```

The populateStats method calls fine and populates the database. The testUpdate method is just one of many that I've tried to update, though nothing seems work. Thanks much in advance.

Comment: share your Dao interface

Comment: "though nothing seems work" -- what does this mean, exactly? How are you determining this? Also, using `allowMainThreadQueries()` [is not a good idea](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/RoomDatabase.Builder.html#allowMainThreadQueries()).

Comment: I'm casting the database entries to TextViews, which display the values after they are inserted but do not reflect any updated values.

Comment: what you are updating? your function `testUpdate` is creating new instance of stats and trying to update it. There is no such newly created `stats` in db so it will not update anything

Comment: Musooff - that was it, thank you. I still make the mistake of creating new things and assuming they refer to previous things. I changed the instantiation to one under the Repository instance and just referred back to that.